# How to add new columns based on row data in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame like below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Col_A         |     Col_B        | Col_C
-------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC1         |      XYZ1        | {json data}
-------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC2         |      XYZ2        | {json data}
-------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC3         |      XYZ3        | {json data}
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to transform `Col_C` josn data for each row and add this transformed data column and value again to row and output will be like below.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Col_A         |     Col_B        | Col_C          | New_Col_1       |..... |New_Col_N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC1         |      XYZ1        | {json data}    | extracted value |..... |extracted value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC2         |      XYZ2        | {json data}    | extracted value |..... |extracted value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ABC3         |      XYZ3        | {json data}    | extracted value |..... |extracted value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the transformation logic which gives me key value pair of `Col_C` json data but how I can add this new columns to row again. As column names are dynamic(Not a fixed schema) i can't use `withColumn` function to add new columns.

One thing which i can do is add unique column and share it with actual data frame and transformed data frame and later do join on that unique column.
Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: The schema is fixed between the rows at least, right?

Comment: yes, schema is fixed for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Since the schema is not known, we can take one json and extract it's schema.

Essentially this would work:

Consider this input

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["ABC1","XYZ1", "{'name':'Sam', 'Age':26}"],["ABC2","XYZ2", "{'name':'Raj', 'Age':26}"]]).toDF("Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C");
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image: Input]

This should do the job:

```
schema = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([df.select("Col_C").first()[('Col_C')]])).schema
df.withColumn("asJson", F.from_json("Col_C", schema)).select(F.col('Col_A'), F.col('Col_B'), F.col('asJson.*')).show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]